# Firebase Realtime Database not ordering data correctly in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I am currently integrating a chat feature in my mobile app and ran into an issue when ordering Firebase Realtime Database documents by their timeStamp.

This is the code that is run on `initState`

```
  getStartData() async {
    DatabaseReference starCountRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('messages/${widget.placeID}');
    starCountRef
        .orderByChild("timeStamp")
        .limitToLast(6)
        .onValue
        .listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      final data = event.snapshot.value as dynamic;
      setState(() {
        list = data.values.toList();
      });
    });
  }
```

This is the result

[image]

The issue isn't with the timeStamp property being incorrect, but with the physical rearrangement itself.

Comment: try to put `.onChildAdded` before your `.listen`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on this code that i read. that you didn't implement the `.onChildAdded`

```
getStartData() async {
    DatabaseReference starCountRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('messages/${widget.placeID}');
    starCountRef
        .orderByChild("timeStamp")
        .limitToLast(6)
        .onValue
        .listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      final data = event.snapshot.value as dynamic;
      setState(() {
        list = data.values.toList();
      });
    });
  }
```

as soon as you call `final data = event.snapshot.value as dynamic` that mean you convert the result, but the values in the map has no place for the relative order of result. base on [this](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/753#issuecomment-805086441) github answer for the issue.